# pyparsing - Big calculations freezing intepreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pyparsing

So here is a parser taken from [`fourFn.py`](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/fourFn.py):

```py
from pyparsing import (
    Literal,
    Word,
    Group,
    Forward,
    alphas,
    alphanums,
    Regex,
    ParseException,
    CaselessKeyword,
    Suppress,
    delimitedList
)
import math
import operator

exprStack = []


def push_first(toks):
    exprStack.append(toks[0])


def push_unary_minus(toks):
    for t in toks:
        if t == "-":
            exprStack.append("unary -")
        else:
            break


bnf = None


def BNF():
    """
    expop   :: '^'
    multop  :: '*' | '/'
    addop   :: '+' | '-'
    integer :: ['+' | '-'] '0'..'9'+
    atom    :: PI | E | real | fn '(' expr ')' | '(' expr ')'
    factor  :: atom [ expop factor ]*
    term    :: factor [ multop factor ]*
    expr    :: term [ addop term ]*
    """
    global bnf
    if not bnf:
        # use CaselessKeyword for e and pi, to avoid accidentally matching
        # functions that start with 'e' or 'pi' (such as 'exp'); Keyword
        # and CaselessKeyword only match whole words
        e = CaselessKeyword("E")
        pi = CaselessKeyword("PI")
        # fnumber = Combine(Word("+-"+nums, nums) +
        #                    Optional("." + Optional(Word(nums))) +
        #                    Optional(e + Word("+-"+nums, nums)))
        # or use provided pyparsing_common.number, but convert back to str:
        # fnumber = ppc.number().addParseAction(lambda t: str(t[0]))
        fnumber = Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?")
        ident = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_$")

        plus, minus, mult, div = map(Literal, "+-*/")
        lpar, rpar = map(Suppress, "()")
        addop = plus | minus
        multop = mult | div
        expop = Literal("^")

        expr = Forward()
        expr_list = delimitedList(Group(expr))
        # add parse action that replaces the function identifier with a (name, number of args) tuple
        def insert_fn_argcount_tuple(t):
            fn = t.pop(0)
            num_args = len(t[0])
            t.insert(0, (fn, num_args))

        fn_call = (ident + lpar - Group(expr_list) + rpar).setParseAction(
            insert_fn_argcount_tuple
        )
        atom = (
            addop[...]
            + (
                (fn_call | pi | e | fnumber | ident).setParseAction(push_first)
                | Group(lpar + expr + rpar)
            )
        ).setParseAction(push_unary_minus)

        # by defining exponentiation as "atom [ ^ factor ]..." instead of "atom [ ^ atom ]...", we get right-to-left
        # exponents, instead of left-to-right that is, 2^3^2 = 2^(3^2), not (2^3)^2.
        factor = Forward()
        factor <<= atom + (expop + factor).setParseAction(push_first)[...]
        term = factor + (multop + factor).setParseAction(push_first)[...]
        bnf <<= term + (addop + term).setParseAction(push_first)[...]
    return bnf


# map operator symbols to corresponding arithmetic operations
epsilon = 1e-12
opn = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "^": operator.pow,
}

fn = {
    "sin": math.sin,
    "cos": math.cos,
    "tan": math.tan,
    "exp": math.exp,
    "abs": abs,
    "trunc": int,
    "round": round,
    "sgn": lambda a: -1 if a < -epsilon else 1 if a > epsilon else 0,
    # functionsl with multiple arguments
    "multiply": lambda a, b: a * b,
    "hypot": math.hypot,
    # functions with a variable number of arguments
    "all": lambda *a: all(a),
}


def evaluate_stack(s):
    op, num_args = s.pop(), 0
    if isinstance(op, tuple):
        op, num_args = op
    if op == "unary -":
        return -evaluate_stack(s)
    if op in "+-*/^":
        # note: operands are pushed onto the stack in reverse order
        op2 = evaluate_stack(s)
        op1 = evaluate_stack(s)
        return opn[op](op1, op2)
    elif op == "PI":
        return math.pi  # 3.1415926535
    elif op == "E":
        return math.e  # 2.718281828
    elif op in fn:
        # note: args are pushed onto the stack in reverse order
        args = reversed([evaluate_stack(s) for _ in range(num_args)])
        return fn[op](*args)
    elif op[0].isalpha():
        raise Exception("invalid identifier '%s'" % op)
    else:
        # try to evaluate as int first, then as float if int fails
        try:
            return int(op)
        except ValueError:
            return float(op)
```

This code works well for small calculations:

```py
>>> import fourFn
>>> fourFn.BNF().parseString("9+9", parseAll=True)
>>> val = fourFn.evaluate_stack(fourFn.exprStack[:])
>>> print(val)
18
>>>
```

but when I try with a big calculation like `"9^9^9"`, the program freezes when trying to compute `val`.

```py
>>> import fourFn
>>> fourFn.BNF().parseString("9^9^9", parseAll=True)
>>> val = fourFn.evaluate_stack(fourFn.exprStack[:])
```

Is it possible to make the evaluation stop and throw an error if it gets too big?

Comment: Please take a look at the `plusminus` package, a pyparsing-based package for evaluating untrusted arithmetic expressions. It includes measures to prevent this kind of DoS attack.  There is also currently a live demo at http://ptmcg.pythonanywhere.com/plusminus

Comment: why not just always treat the number as a `float` rather then trying an an `int` first?  either that or just write your own version of `pow` that does a sanity check first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely not possible because it's Python being slow, not your interpreter. You're trying to compute `9 ** 387420489`, which is a huge number (and Python's integers are virtually unbounded, so it'll just continue computing that integer until it runs out of memory). Since Python can only run one thread at a time, and integer exponentiation is implemented in C, pure Python code has no way of knowing that the interpreter is "stuck" computing something.

You could set up some other code to monitor the execution of this code and kill it if it doesn't terminate in `n` seconds, but that'd probably be overkill. BTW, I've been computing this number for 5 minutes already, and there's still no answer.

Comment: Take a look at the pyparsing-spinoff `plusminus` package. It includes some pre-emptive logic to try to avoid these kinds of attack expressions.

Comment: @TheOneMusic, then you'd need a different integer type. One option is to ignore the overflow by using something like [`ctypes.c_uint32`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint32) (and thus silently, yet very quickly, produce incorrect results in case of overflows); another option may be to use heuristics and check if an expression could blow up, like in `plus minus`; or straight up implement your own bitwise slow-a\*\* integer addition/multiplication that will catch overflows. BTW, `9**387420489` has been running for 20 mins already, consumed 250 MBs of RAM and keeps going

Comment: @ForceBru: In many cases where you're doing exponentiation this large, it's while doing modular arithmetic (e.g. simulating RSA), where it's always followed by modular reduction. In that case, Python supports it directly by passing all three arguments (base, exponent, modulus) to the `pow` function. Sure, `9 ** 9 ** 9` takes forever, but `pow(9, 9 ** 9, 1234567890)` is instant. May not apply to OP's case, but if it doesn't, odds are the OP's case is not sane.

Comment: @ForceBru: Just a FYI: If your python executable reached 250MB of RAM, it was probably about half-way there. On my machine, it takes about 45 minutes, but I don't have the fastest machine in the world, peaking at somewhere under half a gigabyte of resident memory. However, if you asked Python to print the value (perhaps by just typing 9**9**9 into a CLI), it would take roughly forever to convert the number to a string of decimal digits. (Or at least a couple of weeks.) That's something you always have to bear in mind when you're playing around with enormous numbers.